# Trying to understand VOLUME command in dockerfile and its directories

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I've started using docker on my local computer using windows just recently and I'm in a stage where I'm trying to understand volume.
To my understanding, in the commend line you can simply connect local directory to the container directory with adding the command:

```
-v [host location]:[container location]
```

And when using dockerfile you specify the container directory:

```
VOLUME [container location]
```

So when this is running using the

```
docker volume ls
```

I can see a volume created on my computer

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               3d25e0608d5500c4dba29f8c3bc7b5ba4d5348e6fbd54644a20a5701f0b9f427
```

My problem is I try to understand WHERE on my computer this volume is?

using inspect giving me this result:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-05-01T13:47:41Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/3d25e0608d5500c4dba29f8c3bc7b5ba4d5348e6fbd54644a20a5701f0b9f427/_data",
        "Name": "3d25e0608d5500c4dba29f8c3bc7b5ba4d5348e6fbd54644a20a5701f0b9f427",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

and I can't understand WHERE is "/var/lib/docker/volumes/..." exactly.
Is it on the virtual linux drive the docker is using?

Comment: With Docker for Windows and Mac, yes, /var/lib/docker is part of the embedded VM that Docker runs, and not in the host /var/lib/docker directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to be able to directly access Docker named volumes (or anything else that lives in `/var/lib/docker`).  The official Docker examples on, for example, [backup and restore for named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) launch additional containers mounting the same volumes for basic data-management operation.

If you need to directly access the data in a volume, using a host-directory bind-mount is probably the easiest option.

You should avoid writing `VOLUME` directives in your Dockerfile.  You don't need it to use `docker run -v` to mount a directory into a container; its key effect is to automatically add a `-v` option for you if you didn't already have one.  In practice, you'll get no benefit and suffer from some confusing side effects (notably, `RUN` steps will make no persistent changes inside a `VOLUME` directory).

The anonymous volume you're seeing in `docker volume ls` is probably the result of your `VOLUME` directive.